# backend not logging anything

Tags: express, backend

I am trying to host a fullstack website with Vercel. I first had my front and back end in one github repo, but I changed it so now they're in different ones. When I go to the link of the backend page it puts hello world on the page, but it doesn't log the "server started on port (port)" to the console. I've tried everything and I just can't figure it out.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8040;

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I've run it in a terminal and it logs it, and when I did a GET request from the front end (when they were in the same repo) it gave me and error and did send anything.

Answer (score 0):

Vercel is a serverless environment. So it will only log things when a function (endpoint) is called. App execution will be slightly different from a continuous running machine.

[Check the docs on the serverless environment](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel#adapting-to-serverless-environments)

Comment: I don't quite understand. I've run the files locally using postman and I get the response, but when I send the request on the code I don't get anything. I'm sorry for just not understanding